# How to retrieve user's current city name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

How do you retrieve the user's current city name?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

What you have to do is setup a `CLLocationManager` that will find your current coordinates. With the current coordinates you need to use `MKReverseGeoCoder` to find your location.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{  
    // this creates the CCLocationManager that will find your current location
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

// this delegate is called when the app successfully finds your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    // this creates a MKReverseGeocoder to find a placemark using the found coordinates
    MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    geoCoder.delegate = self;
    [geoCoder start];
}

// this delegate method is called if an error occurs in locating your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
 NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);
}

// this delegate is called when the reverseGeocoder finds a placemark
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;
    // with the placemark you can now retrieve the city name
    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressCityKey];
}

// this delegate is called when the reversegeocoder fails to find a placemark
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:%@ didFailWithError:%@", geocoder, error);
}
```

Comment: One note: You have to stash the location manager in an ivar (and maybe stop it again once you've received a location), otherwise it will be immediately autoreleased and you won't receive any delegate callbacks. Also, the reverse geocoder requires an internet connection to work.

Comment: Can you say me how to print Current City Or Location in Title and Subtitle on Pin ???

Comment: @Frade #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

Comment: MKReverseGeoCoder is deprecated since ios 5.0

Comment: Frade, i wish you could have said what you found out... sigh

Answer (score 122):

As of iOS 5 `MKReverseGeoCoder` is Deprecated!

So you want to use `CLGeocoder` with `CLLocationManager`, very simple and works with block.

**Example:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

   CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks) {
                           .... = [placemark locality];
                       }
                   }];
}
```

**Edit:** Instead of a `for in` loop you can also do:

```
NSString *locString = placemarks.count ? [placemarks.firstObject locality] : @"Not Found";
```

Answer (score 28):

This is working fine for me :

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                   if (error){
                       NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                       return;

                   }


                   CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                   NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
                   NSLog(@"placemark.country %@",placemark.country);
                   NSLog(@"placemark.postalCode %@",placemark.postalCode);
                   NSLog(@"placemark.administrativeArea %@",placemark.administrativeArea);
                   NSLog(@"placemark.locality %@",placemark.locality);
                   NSLog(@"placemark.subLocality %@",placemark.subLocality);
                   NSLog(@"placemark.subThoroughfare %@",placemark.subThoroughfare);

               }];
```

Comment: Why does it return an array? strange. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is slick, love blocks.  I'd put a conditional on placemarks array to make sure objectatindex:0 actually exists.

Comment: Hello I am getting an error `kCLErrorDomain error 8` do you know why?

Comment: CLGeoCoder is undeclared what I have to do so it may work what to import and what to add

Answer (score 17):

If anyone is trying to move onto CLGeocoder from MKReverseGeocoder then I have written a blog post that might be of help http://jonathanfield.me/jons-blog/clgeocoder-example.html

Basically an example would be, after you have created locationManager and CLGeocoder objects just add this code to your viewDidLoad() and then make some labels or text areas to show the data.

```
  [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [self.CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {


         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


             isoCountryCode.text = placemark.ISOcountryCode;
             country.text = placemark.country;
             postalCode.text= placemark.postalCode;
             adminArea.text=placemark.administrativeArea;
             subAdminArea.text=placemark.subAdministrativeArea;
             locality.text=placemark.locality;
             subLocality.text=placemark.subLocality;
             thoroughfare.text=placemark.thoroughfare;
             subThoroughfare.text=placemark.subThoroughfare;
             //region.text=placemark.region;



     }];
```

Comment: @macayer Yes, *would* crash if empty, but will never be empty if I understand correctly. Will either contain 1 or more elements or be `nil`, and messages sent to `nil` result in `nil`, as well as property access through dot notation via `nil`. That being said, one should always check if `error` is non-`nil`.

Answer (score 5):

After you setup CLLocationManager you would get location update as a latitude/longitude pair. Then you could use CLGeocoder to convert the coordinate to a user friendly place name.

Here is the sample code in **Swift 4**.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(lastLocation) { [weak self] (placemarks, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let firstLocation = placemarks?[0],
                    let cityName = firstLocation.locality { // get the city name
                    self?.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone needs it in **Swift 3**, this is how I did it:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.first!
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 500, 500)

    self.location = location
    self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()

    // Drop a pin at user's Current Location
    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    myAnnotation.title = "Localização"
    self.mapViewMK.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)

    self.mapViewMK.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.locationManager = nil

    // Get user's current location name
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.location!) { (placemarksArray, error) in

        if (placemarksArray?.count)! > 0 {

            let placemark = placemarksArray?.first
            let number = placemark!.subThoroughfare
            let bairro = placemark!.subLocality
            let street = placemark!.thoroughfare

            self.addressLabel.text = "\(street!), \(number!) - \(bairro!)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to get user's current location and then use MKReverseGeocoder to recognize the city.

There's great example in [iPhone App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), chapter 8.
Once you've got location initialize geocoder, set the delegate and read country from the placemark. Read the documentation for MKReverseGeocodeDelegate and create methods:

- reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:
- reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:

  ```
  MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
  geocoder.delegate = self;
  [geocoder start];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for getting Current City:--

extension YourController: CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {

```
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            return
        }
        else
        {
            if placemarks!.count > 0
            {
                let placeMarksArrray: NSArray = placemarks!
                let pm = placeMarksArrray[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
                manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            } else
            {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        }
    })
}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark!) {
    if (placemark != nil) {
        //stop updating location to save battery life
        locationLocation.stopUpdatingLocation()
        var tempString : String = ""
        if(placemark.locality != nil){
            tempString = tempString +  placemark.locality! + " "
            print(placemark.locality)
        }
        if(placemark.postalCode != nil){
            tempString = tempString +  placemark.postalCode! + " "
            print(placemark.postalCode)
        }
        if(placemark.administrativeArea != nil){
            tempString = tempString +  placemark.administrativeArea! + " "
            print(placemark.administrativeArea)
        }
        if(placemark.country != nil){
            tempString = tempString +  placemark.country! + " "



        }
        let dictForaddress = placemark.addressDictionary as! NSDictionary


        if let city = dictForaddress["City"] {
            print(city)



        }
        strLocation = tempString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my small Swift class which helps me with getting reverse geocoded information about current location. Don't forget about `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` field in `Info.plist`.

```
class CurrentPlacemarkUpdater: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    private(set) var latestPlacemark: CLPlacemark?
    var onLatestPlacemarkUpdate: (() -> ())?
    var shouldStopOnUpdate: Bool = true

    func start() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stop() {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    fileprivate func updatePlacemark(for location: CLLocation) {
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { [weak self] placemarks, error in
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                self?.latestPlacemark = placemark
                self?.onLatestPlacemarkUpdate?()
                if self?.shouldStopOnUpdate ?? false {
                    self?.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            updatePlacemark(for: location)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("CurrentPlacemarkUpdater: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// place the function code below in desire location in program.

// [self getCurrentLocation];



-(void)getCurrentLocation
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self->locationManager.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;

                       }


                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                       NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.country %@",placemark.country);
                        NSLog(@"placemark.locality %@",placemark.locality );
                       NSLog(@"placemark.postalCode %@",placemark.postalCode);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.administrativeArea %@",placemark.administrativeArea);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.locality %@",placemark.locality);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.subLocality %@",placemark.subLocality);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.subThoroughfare %@",placemark.subThoroughfare);

                   }];
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Read the documentation for [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) -- the documentation, guides & sample applications are provided by Apple for a reason.

Comment: MKReverseGeoCoder is deprecated