# Reverse geocode street name and city as text

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I have been having some trouble finding a good way to output just the street name and city as text (Infinite Loop, Cupertino shown here) that can be displayed in my iPhone app. This needs to be able to dynamically change as you change streets and city. I don't have the slightest idea of how to do this, I hope someone can help. I have attached a *very* rough image of what I am trying to acheave.

I have found this  (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) for google maps about how to reverse geocode using javascript, but what I do not understand is how this would be done in a iPhone development setting. I work in web design and I see how it would be done in HTML but I am very new to iPhone development and don't have the slightest clue of how it would be done here.

If someone could spell out how to do this I would be extremely grateful. I cannot seem to find what I am looking for by searching Google.

Reference picture:

[alt text http://www.threepixeldrift.com/images/deep-storage/reversegeocodeiphoneapp.jpg](http://www.threepixeldrift.com/images/deep-storage/reversegeocodeiphoneapp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the iPhone, use [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

This question has a more complete code example:

[How to retrieve user's current city name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrive-users-current-city-name)

Comment: Yes I have seen that but I was wondering if someone could show me a example