# Fetch Location Name from Coordinates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation

I have already Fetched the name of location through coordinates.

with this code

```
    reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
```

here newLocation having my current location

and reverseGeocoder is the type of MKReverseGeocoder.

I also add the framework MapKit and add delegate MKReverseGeocoderDelegate.

and define this delegate in .m file

```
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{...}
```

when we start this delegate and get the location with (MKPlacemark*)placemark after that i show this with in an AlertView in above delegate method or any other user defined method like:

```
[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Place" 
message:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",placemark] autorelease] 
delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" 
otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
```

**Problem is that my alert view is appeared again and again in every second.**

so please let me know how to stop the reverseGeocoder or how i can see this alert view just once.

thanx in advance.

Comment: are you show user current location ?

Comment: yes this code is showing my current location, but its shows alert view in every second.

Comment: because you current location update that's why this problem was  raised. please stop to update your current location. or use a bool variable.    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
// locationManager is your CLLocationManager

Comment: @user994813 assume that  we stop locationManager and in future if we agin want to update location but don't want to get the location name we want to get only coordinates. than what to do???

Comment: just simple you add one bool variable like isalert = FALSE; then whenever you call alertview just check if(!isalert) {// display alert view and dont forget isalert =TRUE} else {//nothing} so next time it get true so alertview not call.

Comment: what to do if we again want to see this alertview. with your condition it is shown only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is create , Because you have every time new location , this problem is remove from two way...
1) use distance condition between two location ...and when your distance is greater then a particular distance then you see alert view.....

2)if use want to see alert once time then use this code...

```
int count = 0;
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{

.......
if(count == 0)
{
[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Place" 
message:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",placemark] autorelease] 
delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" 
otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];

count ++;

}
}
```

3)concept

NSString *previousloaction;/// use like global variable...
NSString *currentloaction;/// use like global variable...

```
  -(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
    {
    currentloaction=placemark;
    .......
   if(![previousloaction isEqucaltoString: currentloaction])
    {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Place" 
    message:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",placemark] autorelease] 
    delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];

   previousloaction =currentloaction;

    }
    }
```

Comment: if You are any problem then see this url (i have use this conecpt )http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrive-users-current-city-name

Comment: i have seen this link, they have value in NSSTring *city; but they are not displaying that anywhere.

Comment: if count is incremented and in future if i again want to get the name of location how is it possible???

Comment: if You want to again location in alert view then use my first concept

Comment: next concept that you save location ..when again location name get then check the  previous location to current location when both location is not name then count==0 use

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7489/discussion-between-user1186899-and-chander-shakher-ghorela-guru)