# How To Find Out Address From longitude and Latitude in iOS?

Tags: ios

I Want to place annotations on the Map based on the  given longitude and latitude?
Can anybody help me to solve this problem with Simple code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) class if you target for iOS ≥ 5.0, or [MKReverseGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323) class for iOS 4.

Comment: Just Refer techotopia/iPhone material,provided nice example on "How to find out longitude and latitude" and "How to annotate the pinpoint on the given longitude and latitude"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrive-users-current-city-name). Try to search thru stackoverflow before asking questions…

Comment: Already provided solutions in stack overflow are not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

That's called `reverse geocoding` and can be done with the [`CLGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder) (iOS5) or [`MKReverseGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKReverseGeocoder) (iOS3+5) class.

Here is a tutorial for `CLGeocoder`: [click](http://jonathanfield.me/jons-blog/clgeocoder-example.html)