# How to find current location in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve user's current city name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrieve-users-current-city-name)

i am working on gps based application ,i want to fetch current location in iphone,how i can fetch it.like delhi ,chandigrah.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current geo position with CLLocationManager and fetch the location with MKReverseGeocoder or Google API

Answer (score 0):

Use CoreLocation Framework. With CLLocation Manager you can get your current location details 
.

Answer (score -1):

If you're writing a native application in Objective-C, there are plenty of resources out there that answer your question. I'd recommend you start with Apples own documentation, then come back with a more detailed question if you have specific problems:

**Introduction:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

**How to:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html