# GMSGeocoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate: completion handler not called (iOS - Google Maps SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object which contains the coordinate of a location.

I want to set the property `city` (`NSString`) to the city name of this location.

Note: I'm using `Google Maps iOS SDK` if it's matters.

Note II: I'm not using `-reverseGeocoder: didFindPlacemark:` so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrieve-users-current-city-name) is not relevant for me.

The completion handler block is never called.

**GMSGeoCode code**:

```
 //Checking user's city
        __block NSString *userCity;
        [[GMSGeocoder geocoder]reverseGeocodeCoordinate:self.locationManager.location.coordinate completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {//skips completionHandler for some reason
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
            }
            userCity=[[[response results] firstObject] locality];
        }];
        //Checking saved city
        __block NSString *arounderCity;
        [[GMSGeocoder geocoder]reverseGeocodeCoordinate:arounder.radiusCircularRegion.center completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
            }
            arounderCity=[[[response results] firstObject] locality];
        }];
        if ([userCity isEqualToString:arounderCity]) {
            return YES;
        }
```

Anyone have an idea how to get the city name?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve user's current city name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrieve-users-current-city-name)

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Edited the post

Comment: Do you have a valid Google Maps key, properly configured? Does your location manager have a valid location? Simplify your test by passing a hard coded Location coordinate instead of querying Core Location.

Comment: @HalMueller everything is fine and working, the geoCoder is the only problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GMSGeoCoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate: completionHandler: on background thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434026/gmsgeocoder-reversegeocodecoordinate-completionhandler-on-background-thread)