# GMSGeoCoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate: completionHandler: on background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to get the city name from 2 coordinates (I'm using `GMSGeoCoder` `-reverseGeocodeCoordinate: completionHandler:` method) and then to comapre the objects.

The problem is that the method is running on a background thread (not in the main thread) and when I try to compare (using `if` statement) the objects (`userCity` and `storeCity`- both `NSString`) is still nil.

My code:

```
//Checking user's city
        __block NSString *userCity;
        [[GMSGeocoder geocoder]reverseGeocodeCoordinate:self.locationManager.location.coordinate completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
            }
            userCity=[[[response results] firstObject] locality];
        }];
        //Checking store's city
        __block NSString *storeCity;
        [[GMSGeocoder geocoder]reverseGeocodeCoordinate:arounder.radiusCircularRegion.center completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
            }
            arounderCity=[[[response results] firstObject] locality];
        }];
        if ([userCity isEqualToString:arounderCity]) {
            return YES;
        }
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: yes, wait for blocks and proceed then!

Comment: @Daij-Djan That's basically what I want to do, but how can I do that? Can you please give me a code example?

Comment: I wrote one. please be aware I wrote it inline and there may be smaller typos but it will give you the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your code to proceed after the async tasks are done:

This also has the benefit that you don't actively wait for stuff and block the main thread

## e.g.:

```
- (void)checkCitiesWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL same))
    //Checking user's city
    [[GMSGeocoder geocoder]reverseGeocodeCoordinate:self.locationManager.location.coordinate completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
        }
        id userCity=[[[response results] firstObject] locality];

        //Checking store's city
        [[GMSGeocoder geocoder]reverseGeocodeCoordinate:arounder.radiusCircularRegion.center completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
            }
            id arounderCity=[[[response results] firstObject] locality];

            same ([userCity isEqualToString:arounderCity]);
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I will call `-checkCitiesWithCompletionBlock:` on a function that returns BOOL, what should I return outside the completion?

Comment: if you want.. I don't advise it .. wait for the block to finish. But the outer api should rather be async too IMO. how to wait for a block I also answered on SO before so that might help you :)