# Check if 2 locations are in the same city

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a location called `savedLocation` that contains a location that I've pre-saved to my app.

I want to check if the `savedLocation` and the user's current location are in the same city.

**Creating the CLCircularRegion (saveLocation)**:

```
-(CLCircularRegion*)createCircularRegion
{
    CLCircularRegion *region=[[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:self.geoPoint radius:200 identifier:self.identifier];

    region.notifyOnEntry=YES;

    return region;
}
```

Note: this question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434026/gmsgeocoder-reversegeocodecoordinate-completionhandler-on-background-thread) because in this question I ask how to compare 2 different location's city (without getting nil), the "duplicate" question is about a different thing.

Anyone have an idea how can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show your code of `savedLocation`

Comment: @Anbu. Karthik `savedLocation` is basically a `CLCircularRegion` object (and I want to compare the center of it), I'll post the code for the creation of the object.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Updated the post with the code, please take a look

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Can you please help me?

Comment: Sry bro forgive me i dont knw ur concept

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik What do you need to know? I'll answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Reverse Geocoder to get the city name of your location. Then compare it with the city name of your reference location. I think this might be inaccurate.

```
- (void)getCityNameFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle the error here
            return;
        }
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", placemark.locality);
    }];
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought to do but `reverseGeocodeLocation: completionHandler :` is running in a background thread (and I need to do it twice because I need to compare 2 locations) so when it gets to the `if` statement the `NSString` object (2 object - one for each city) is still `nil`, how can I handle it?

Comment: @audience I wrote the same thing in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434026/gmsgeocoder-reversegeocodecoordinate-completionhandler-on-background-thread/35434233#35434233. This qs is a duplicate by the same author

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks! So I won't look into it any further.

Comment: @audience I was saying the OP is cross posting, your answer is sound id say

Comment: @Daij-Djan I've updated this post with an exlenation why this post it different from the question you posted, I'll appriciate if you'll remove the "duplicate" mark from this question, thanks :)

Comment: no. you don't explain why it is different at all which you can ALSO see by the way you got identical answers :)

Comment: "I ask how to compare 2 different location's city (without getting nil), the "duplicate" question is about a different thing." ??? sounds quite same. and using GPS is async :)